# Firefox: "Error loading script"

Tags: javascript, firefox

"Error loading script" occurs under FireFox 3 if I "quickly click" different links on my web site (Asp.Net MVC + jQuery, full postbacks). It is rather easy task to reproduce this bug. But I cannot understand why it occurs? Every time it shows different failed script file. All JavaScript files are included before closing  tag.

Errors are trapped in window.onerror handler. If I simply ignore errors with message 'Error loading script' everything works fine. But this seems to be not the best solution, there must be some reason. It's a pity but this post was not helpful for me: [Firefox ‘Error loading script’ loading Google Analytics in FF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192570/firefox-error-loading-script-loading-google-analytics-in-ff2)

Another resources that describe similar problem:

[Browser Scripting Errors ...](http://www.web-wise-wizard.com/javascript-tutorials/error-loading-script-firefox-errors.html)

[Firefox 'Error loading script ' issue when implementing GA scripts.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=12f5f72a7071cef8&hl=en)

There is error log entry:

```
Error message: "Error loading script"
Location.href: http://blah-blah-blah/General
Url: http://blah-blah-blah/Scripts/localization/locale-uk.js
Line: 1
UserAgent: mozilla, 1.9.0.11
```

Can you help me with this annoying bug? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug's error console (the FF add-on)? It may provide a more information.

Comment: FireBug tells nothing, only window.onerror handler can detect this error

Comment: "Error loading script" is not reported via `window.onerror` in Firefox 14+: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#Browser_compatibility), [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737087).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're quickly clicking between links, you may simply be interrupting the load process of some of the GA scripts at different points (hence the randomness).

Perhaps when you do that and you get an error message, it may only apply to the page that was previously loaded.

Comment: Yes, I have similar suggestions. But I do not understand why FireFox throws error for 'already unloaded page'? IE for example silently do nothing in this case. Looks like that simply ignoring this error is best real solution.

Comment: This is indeed the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192570/firefox-error-loading-script-loading-google-analytics-in-ff2/7686057#7686057 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly answered in a previous post already

[Firefox 'Error loading script' loading Google Analytics in FF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192570/firefox-error-loading-script-loading-google-analytics-in-ff2/7686057#7686057)

This problem occurs when leaving a page in Firefox before all scripts have finished loading. So I assume that it is safe to ignore the error.

You don't see this error in the Firefox error console, but you can make it visible by binding an alert to the window.onerror event. Then you will be able to see the alert box for a small amount of time and get the following error in the error console:

[11:35:57.428] uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 462"  data: no]
I'm using the following check to ignore this error in my onerror handler:

if (navigator.userAgent.search('Firefox') != -1 && message === 'Error loading script') {
    // Firefox generates this error when leaving a page before all scripts have finished loading
    return;
}